# Savvis.net blocking routing

Tags: networking, routing

My website and server are unreachable due to routing for the network block 69.70.44.0/24 seems to be routed from Europe to savvis.net.  Then routinbg stops at a router identified as trl-pos-0-3-2-0.chicago.savvis.net [204.70.192.101].  I have had no luck contacting either savvis.net or my ISP (Videotron.net).  Are there any other options for getting this corrected?  Anyone's help would be appreciated.  MTR trace extracts (with and without name lookups).  Thanks.

```
|------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|                                      WinMTR statistics                                   |
|                       Host              -   %  | Sent | Recv | Best | Avrg | Wrst | Last |
|------------------------------------------------|------|------|------|------|------|------|

|      te1-3.parse1.Paris.opentransit.net -   50 |    2 |    1 |    0 |  195 |  195 |  195 |
|                          208.175.185.73 -   50 |    2 |    1 |    0 |  130 |  130 |  130 |
| cr1-tengig-0-1-2-0.londonuk1.savvis.net -   50 |    2 |    1 |    0 |  199 |  199 |  199 |
|      cr1-pos-0-3-2-0.chicago.savvis.net -   50 |    2 |    1 |    0 |  284 |  284 |  284 |
|                   No response from host -  100 |    2 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |

|                         193.251.128.162 -    0 |    1 |    1 |   87 |   87 |   87 |   87 |
|                          208.175.185.73 -    0 |    1 |    1 |   91 |   91 |   91 |   91 |
|                          204.70.207.177 -    0 |    1 |    1 |  102 |  102 |  102 |  102 |
|                          204.70.192.101 -    0 |    1 |    1 |  217 |  217 |  217 |  217 |
|                   No response from host -  100 |    1 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is absolutely *nothing* anyone can do about this except for Savvis employees. It appears the contact info you should use is: ipnoc@savvis.net, 1-800-213-5127.

Comment: Thanks for the contact info.  Everything is back up after the line drop was replaced. MTR is responding appropriately. It appears my ISP may not have been announcing routing for my IP address block.  They are the next hop after savvis.  Further investigation will be required when I return home.

Answer (score 1):

Your net block isnt visible in any looking glass I've checked (including savvis), all show the same /18 aggregate from cable&wireless. google for bgp looking glass and one of the tier one providers to have a look.

Comment: Thanks for the lookup.  Finally got throuth to my ISP and they report the Modem at my end seems dead. Diagnostic traces from here still end at savvis.net in Chicago.  A technitian is showing up early Monday AM to see what the problem is.